# uninitialized constant in mailer preview

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

so I'm setting up my first mailer in Rails. I used `rails g mailer UserMailer new_session` to generate a mailer, and in my mailer controller user_mailer.rb I have:

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: "example@gmail.com"

  def new_session(user)
  @user = user
  mail to: user.email, subject: "Test!"
  end
end
```

And in my spec/mailers/previews/user_mailer_preview.rb I have:

```
class UserMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
  def new_session
    user = User.first
    UserMailerMailer.new_session(user)
  end
end
```

And when I visited `http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers/user_mailer/new_session` I got an error saying that

```
uninitialized constant UserMailerPreview::UserMailerMailer
```

And the error it shows is this line:

```
UserMailerMailer.new_session(User.first)
```

Not sure where I did wrong. Any pointers? Thanks a million!

Comment: You don't have a class named `UserMailerMailer`, do you? Try `UserMailer.new_session(User.first)` and see what happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `UserMailer.new_session(User.first)`.